# refrer function name in ajax, reverse callback on fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have no idea how I can achieve this.
I am using  jQuery 1.9 for ajax call back.

I have a function, let's say:

```
function a (param){

    //calling a function this will perform ajax
    data = performAjax(param, url, etc);

    // render response
    renderResponse(data);
}
```

We are executing our ajax in perform ajax function.
Issue is when ajax fails then it perform ajaxError function.
I put a message in div that please refresh this again.

But **how can I get function a and all the parameter of that in ajaxError function**? So that I can put a link to refresh again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but here it goes:

```
function performAjax() {
    return $.ajax({
        ....
    });
}

var lastFailedFunction;

function a (param){
    var args = arguments;

    //calling a function this will perform ajax
    performAjax().then(function(data) { // on success
        // render reponse
        renderResponse(data);
    }, function() { // on failure
        lastFailedFunction = function() {
            a.apply(a, args);
        };
        // now you can call lastFailedFunction() to try again
    });
}
```

When the ajax-call fails, it will store the failed function call to `lastFailedFunction`. So somewhere else you might show this message:

```
<div>Function A failed, <a href="#" onclick="lastFailedFunction(); return false;">click here</a> to try again</div>
```

Comment: friend this is good if ajax is inside that function.but i made a global function to perform ajax. $.ajax is in another function as u can see from my question!

Comment: That's no problem if you let `performAjax` return the result of `$.ajax`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using ***error*** callback of ajax, you can get the error message

```
function a(param) {
    var performAjax = $.ajax({
      type: "",
      url: "",
      data: "",
      success: function(msg){
           //success msg
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         //can access param of fun a and the error message
        //append it to the body
        $('body').append('<div>'+param+' error: '+errorThrown+'</div>');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: friend this is good if ajax is inside that function.but i made a global function to perform ajax. $.ajax is in another function as u can see from my question!

Comment: @developerCK I understood, can we pass the function name in it?  example `data = performAjax(param, url, a);`

Comment: @developerCK you're function be like `performAjax (param ,url , fuctionName) {
 $.ajax({
    type: "",
    url: "",
    data: "",
    success: function(msg){
      //success msg
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //can access param of fun a and the error message
   //append it to the body
   $('body').append('<div>'+'function: '+fuctionName+param+' 
                     error: '+errorThrown+'</div>');
    }
  });
}`